# The Dirichlet series of the Hasse–Weil L-function

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, reference-request

I have the following question:
Is there is a paper claiming that the Dirichlet series of the Hasse–Weil $L$-function (associated with an elliptic curve over rationals) is of finite order.
Thank you in advance. I cannot find any result in the net.

Comment: I added the reference-request tag since this question asking for just that.

Comment: What makes a dirchlet series finite order?

Comment: Please see this link to clarify the idea: 
http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M259.06/prod.pdf

Comment: I deleted an answer I gave, as it could create unnecessary complications. @Zeraoulia: could you please make it a habit to ask what you *actually* want. From the comment on my deleted answer it appears you in fact have a paper claiming the result you ask about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without the modularity theorem we don't even know that $L(E,s)$ is entire. The modularity theorem implies that $L(E,s)$ is the $L$-function of a holomorphic cusp form (for a congruence subgroup), for which it follows by the functional equation and the Phragmén-Lindelöf convexity principle that it is of order 1 (and much more).